# JQuery Rails extract divs from HTML string and insert into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**SOLUTION**

```
$('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).html($(data).find('div.chatboxhead'));
$('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).append($(data).find('div.chatboxcontent'));
$('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).append($(data).find('div.chatboxinput'));
```

---

I am using an AJAX call to retrieve data from a controller and then insert it into a particular div. I'm building with Rails 5.

For some reason, the AJAX call returns a duplicate of the entire HTML DOM (in the form of a string) along side of the desired inserted HTML tags.

The following error seems to be pointing to the issue: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

My AJAX call looks like this...

```
$.get("chatrooms/" + conversation_id,  function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).html(data);
    $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
}, "html");
```

From the `console.log()` above I can see an the entire HTML DOM with the desired insertions...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Attr</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="MLx0eod42jFrFPfeZjLcQvgJgGzSv+mChtVczKSTtu+6U1hLCTCzyWnpGLOVYbEvhsEmdw0VWXdppRpc32juxQ==" />
     ...you get the point
```

`console.log(conversation_id);` outputs the correct ID `3`

Here is the full output of my console log... I'm thinking something is weird here, it re-renders `Rendering chatrooms/show.html.erb within layouts/application` and `Rendered chatrooms/show.html.erb within layouts/application` and `Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb`

```
   Started POST "/chatrooms" for ::1 at 2016-07-23 14:48:56 -0400
Processing by ChatroomsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"sender_id"=>"1", "recipient_id"=>"2"}
  Chatroom Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."sender_id" = $1 AND "chatrooms"."recipient_id" = $2  [["sender_id", "1"], ["recipient_id", "2"]]
  Chatroom Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."sender_id" = $1 AND "chatrooms"."recipient_id" = $2 ORDER BY "chatrooms"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["sender_id", "1"], ["recipient_id", "2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/chatrooms/3" for ::1 at 2016-07-23 14:48:56 -0400
Processing by ChatroomsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Chatroom Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering chatrooms/show.html.erb within layouts/application
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."chatroom_id" = $1  [["chatroom_id", 3]]
  Rendered chatrooms/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 98.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

The GET AJAX request calls the following action...

```
def show
  @conversation = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
  @reciever = User.where(:id => @conversation.recipient_id).first
  @messages = Message.where(:chatroom_id => params[:id])
  @message = Message.new
  # debugger
end
```

Comment: No the error is related. Please to log the url of the ajax call?

Comment: I should've suspected -- updated. The javascript console only outputs the included error message.

Comment: Remove first the error related to GET `/sounds`. (and it will be appreciated if you shrink your codes to smaller ones, only targetting your issue, For example, there is no need for controller code here is it is tested and give valid response object)

Comment: Apologies, let me restructure this post...

Comment: about my first comment, I meant `console.log(conversation_id)` before making the ajax call

Comment: Added that ^^ but that doesn't appear to be the issue. If you check my Rails console, I find it odd that it is re-rendering view files... All of this is happening inside a `.click()` function ... adding that now. **UPDATE** I think the controller code is important, because it is what's causing the rendering

Comment: you could try: $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).html($(data).find('div.container'));

Comment: Adding solution now, turns out there were two different containers, so I just sort of hacked it together -- solution added

Comment: Please put the answer into an answer, not the question, and remove the "(Solved)" part of the title, to keep in line with SO posting guidelines.

Comment: It's more likely you're not properly accepting and rendering a JS response, or if you actually mean to return HTML, you shouldn't be using the default layout.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of that guideline. Where should I put my answer (example post)? My thoughts were along the lines of your second guess, I shouldn't be using the default layout, but how do I prevent rails from rendering the default?

Comment: The Rails rendering/templates guide discussed how to not use a layout. As for where to put an answer... fill in the answer text input or click the "Add Answer" button? Is the UX so bad it's impossible to figure it out?